# Creating a timed game in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Im currently programming a simple game in c++ console application. I want to display a timer in realtime that starts when the first action it performed, and stops the game when the timer reaches a pre determined time, such as 5 minutes. I have no idea how to do this in c++ so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance, John.

Comment: You could use `SetTimer` for ending the game.

Comment: You need to be more spcific on what you are having trouble with, tracking the time or having it display in real-time in the console?

Answer (score 2):

you can use gettime() at the start of the game to get the start time. during the game, use the same method and subtract from the start time to check for the desired duration. you may create a separate process for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctime>                // ctime is still quite useful
clock_t start = clock();        // gets number of clock ticks since program start

clock_t end = 5 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // this is 5 seconds * number of ticks per second

// later, in game loop
if (clock() - start) > end { // clock() - start returns the current ticks minus the start ticks. we check if that is more than how many we wanted.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main ()
{


    unsigned int x_hours=0;
    unsigned int x_minutes=0;
    unsigned int x_seconds=0;
    unsigned int x_milliseconds=0;
    unsigned int totaltime=0,count_down_time_in_secs=0,time_left=0;

    clock_t x_startTime,x_countTime;
    count_down_time_in_secs=10;  // 1 minute is 60, 1 hour is 3600


    x_startTime=clock();  // start clock
    time_left=count_down_time_in_secs-x_seconds;   // update timer

    while (time_left>0) 
    {
        x_countTime=clock(); // update timer difference
        x_milliseconds=x_countTime-x_startTime;
        x_seconds=(x_milliseconds/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))-(x_minutes*60);
        x_minutes=(x_milliseconds/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))/60;
        x_hours=x_minutes/60;




        time_left=count_down_time_in_secs-x_seconds; // subtract to get difference 


        printf( "\nYou have %d seconds left  ",time_left,count_down_time_in_secs);
    }


    printf( "\n\n\nTime's out\n\n\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for answer you may use Easylogging++ performance tracking feature

See [this link](https://github.com/easylogging/easyloggingpp#performance-tracking); and [this](https://github.com/easylogging/easyloggingpp/blob/master/samples/STL/timed-block.cpp) and [this](https://github.com/easylogging/easyloggingpp/blob/master/samples/STL/timed-scope.cpp) samples

(Disclosure, I am primary author of this library, not trying to advertise but since this feature works as for this question so mentioning this)